# How to upload texttracks in vimeo using node js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, vimeo

I have a Vimeo account and I have uploaded videos programmatically to vimeo using node js. Now I have to upload the texttracks(.srt,.vtt files) using node js. I got this link from Vimeo support : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/texttracks? But this is not so helpful as I want to implement it using node js. Please help with the same. Thanks.

Comment: Please share [the code you already have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question

Comment: Is there a specific part of the documentation you don't understand?